# Why does R use factors to store characters?

Tags: r

What effect does it have on the code's compile speed and memory allocation ?

I was wondering if I use `stringAsFactors = FALSE`, will it significantly affect my code's compilation time or will the impact be insignificant ?

Answer (score 3):

In the old days it made a difference to memory allocation because factors stored only the unique values of strings, but for a long time now (decades?) R has also used hash tables to store strings, so at present it should make an insignificant difference.

According to Thomas Lumley's [blog post about stringsAsFactors](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/):

> Around June of 2007, R introduced hashing of CHARSXP elements in the underlying C code thanks to Seth Falcon. What this meant was that effectively, character strings were hashed to an integer representation and stored in a global table in R. Anytime a given string was needed in R, it could be referenced by its underlying integer. This effectively put in place, globally, the factor encoding behavior of strings from before. Once this was implemented, there was little to be gained from an efficiency standpoint by encoding character variables as factor.